# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Short cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer when sorting

Tags: java, sorting, java-7, classcastexception

How to sort hashmap by value if the values are  `Short` type  `HashMap<Long, Short>()`?

when I use generic sorting like

```
public static <K extends Comparable<K>, V extends Comparable<V>> Map<K, V> sortByValues(final Map<K, V> map) {
    Comparator<K> valueComparator =  new Comparator<K>() {
        public int compare(K k1, K k2) {
            int compare = map.get(k1).compareTo(map.get(k2));
            return compare != 0 ? compare : k1.compareTo(k2);
        }
    };
    Map<K, V> sortedByValues = new TreeMap<K, V>(valueComparator);
    sortedByValues.putAll(map);
    return sortedByValues;
}
```

I get this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Short cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values)

Comment: The problem may be with your input data. Can you provide a small example where you call this method? @Jabob G: I do not agree that this is a duplicate, the problem is the ClassCastException and not sorting by value

Answer (score 1):

There are no explicit typecasts anywhere in this code.

Therefore, I conclude that the `ClassCastException` is caused by the implicit typecasts that the compiler inserts when you assign a value returned by some generic method to a variable with a specific type.

Furthermore, since the implicit typecasts only fail in circumstances where you have / someone has choosen to ignore or suppress Java compiler warnings about unsafe conversions, etcetera, I conclude that

- this must have happened, and
- it is the cause of your problem.

In short, the cause of problem is not in the code you have included in the question.  It is somewhere else ...

---

In future, be sure to include:

- Sufficient context to allow people to **see** how your code is being used.  Ideally an MCVE.
- The complete stacktrace for the exceptions.